# Clear cache of a chart

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I have a div container in html with an id "chartQuestion".

```
<div id="chartQuestion"></div>
```

An event in javascript listens to changes on a select, that is, if I choose item 1 of the select, I launch a function to create a pie chart; If I choose item 2 of the select, I launch a function to create a serial chart on the same div. The problem is that when using the same div to display the graphics, they overlap. Any idea what to do in these cases? Is this a mistake of mine? Is there any way to clear amchart cache?

Comment: https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptmaps/AmChart#clear

Comment: you need to destroy the chart instance before creating the new chart. they are different way to do it. if you can share your code. we can help you to do it